# App login page not shown - Android Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-layout

I am trying to get to the app login screen on Facebook. When the activity is started, the screen shows a facebook loading page then disappears and the page is set to the R.layout.main.

I must be missing the point here, but how do I get to the app login page for the user to login please.

I have been following the tutorial based at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso

FYI - I have removed the APP_ID

```
package com.example.facebook;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;


public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("APP_ID");
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*
         * Get existing access_token if any
         */
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        /*
         * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
         */
        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {}
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Is Facebook native App installed in your phone? And also check you are getting error like Login failed in Logcat

Comment: I am getting the message: 04-24 15:54:05.050: D/CLIPBOARD(21628): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems your Mobile contains Facebook Native App so , it might throws **login failed invalid key error** in Logcat.

If it happens that is problem due to [Single Sign On](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso) .. So you need to create Android Key Hash and register in your app..

Follow this [Steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso) to do so.

You can disable Single Sign On in Single line and no need to use Create Hash Key but **this is not recommended way to handle**.

Add **-1** or **Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH** in to **authorize()**

```
facebookObject.authorize(context, PERMISSIONS,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,new LoginListener());
```

Comment: In my case, there is also one problem that I did not enable "Configure Android SSO" when I registered Facebook App.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where I read this, but there might be a bug anywhere so try to set the **activityCode** in **authorize**() to **-1**.

use method:
authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int activityCode, DialogListener listener)

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, -1, new DialogListener(){..});
```

If you use **ActivityGroups**, don't use the current activity itself but the group :

```
 facebook.authorize(activity.getParent(), new String[] {}, -1, new DialogListener(){..});
```

(Expecting the parent of your activity is the ActivityGroup)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener()..etc
```

to

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                    new DialogListener())..etc
```

This forces the dialog to show.

Answer (score 0):

Did u set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the manifest?
Is the latest Version of the fb app installed? Did u replace (not just remove) "APP_ID" with your ID?
Furthermore: is there any error logged in your logcat?
From the ordinary this should work... u are in the uiThread, your code doesn't differ that much from the sampleCode... and hey, it's not rocketScience...

Comment: Yes it's in the manifest file, yes the latest version is installed, Yes to replacing the APP_ID