# Facebook connect is not working

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated Facebook in my app. It works great on many phones like Samsung Galaxy, HTC Desire, Samsung Nexus. But its not working on **AT&T Infuse** and its OS 2.2.1. On clicking Fb Login button, it went to the Facebook login screen (blue bar at top, white blank main with loading box). Stayed there about 2 seconds, then flipped back with no messages. I pressed Facebook Login again and got same behavior. I have native fb app android. Is there any kind of restrictions of Locale, TimeZone or any other from Facebook?
Kindly help me fixing this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please replace below line in **Facebook.java**

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, final DialogListener listener) {
//      authorize(activity, new String[] {}, DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE,listener);//original
        authorize(activity, new String[] {}, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, listener);
    }



public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            final DialogListener listener) {
//      authorize(activity, permissions, DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE, listener); //original
        authorize(activity, permissions, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, listener);
    }
```

Used this code. may be work.

Comment: This is not the right way to solve this issue. He should created Key Hash and register with FB account. This is not recommended solution.

Comment: I have created key and registered with FB account.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is due to **Single Sign On in Android**. So you need to create **HashKey** and register your App Key with Facebook account.. For reference check this link .

[Login Error Problem in Facebook Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299990/app-login-page-not-shown-android-facebook/10300641#10300641).

Comment: If HashKey is the problem, then it should not work on other devices also?

Comment: Yeah you are Right , but you should mention that you registered Hash Key. Okay you are getting any Errors?

Comment: Where i have to mention that HashKey is registered? No there are no errors.

Comment: Did you added Key into Facebook account?

Comment: Yup, I added that key in Facebook account and also created app on Facebook.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy, HTC Desire, Samsung Nexus having Facebook native App?

Comment: Samsung Nexus have Facebook native app.

Comment: Okay do one thing..This is for Testing purpose.. Add one more parameter as mentioned in my link -1 or Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH and check all devices

Comment: When we register on FB, is there any restriction from facebook i.e. name of app should be same or any thing like this?

Comment: In my case, there is also one problem that I did not enable "Configure Android SSO" when I registered Facebook App.

Comment: The link provided by you, have same answer as given by @Nik. But you comment there that "This is not the right way to solve this issue. He should created Key Hash and register with FB account. This is not recommended solution."